# Scroll to a element onClick JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So my HTML looks like this :

```
<section id="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="ul-main_wrapper">
      <li class="item_1""></li>
      <li class="item_2"></li>
      <li class="item_3"></li>
      <li class="item_4"></li>
      <li class="item_5"></li>
      <li class="item_6"></li>
      <li class="item_7"></li>
      <li class="item_8"></li>
      <li class="item_9"></li>
      <li class="item_10"></li>
      <li class="close_clear">Back</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have a list that sits all onto one line so the CSS looks like :

```
#nav-wrapper {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    bottom: 80px;
}

#ul-main_wrapper li {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

onClick of the last item in the list that is back i'm trying to get the list to scroll back to the first item. But can't find anything that works.

**EDIT :**

Here's a JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/svuh0mvj/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use scrollTop():

```
$('.close_clear').on('click', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($('.item_1').offset().top);
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/svuh0mvj/)

Or with animate:

```
$('.close_clear').on('click', function() {
    var body = $("html, body");
    body.stop().animate({scrollTop:$('.item_1').offset().top}, '500');
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/svuh0mvj/2/)

To scroll to the left within your `#nav-header` div, use:

```
$('.close_clear').on('click', function() {
    var nav = $("#nav-wrapper");
    nav.animate({scrollLeft: $('.item_1').offset().left}, '500');
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/svuh0mvj/3/)

Comment: I think you mean `$(window).scrollTop($('.item_1').offset().top);`.  Problem: https://jsfiddle.net/tmkd7wdu/.  Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/tmkd7wdu/1

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/svuh0mvj/1/ @mmm here's the updated fiddle. I can't scrollTop because the list is side by side

Comment: Would have been a good idea to put that in the original question... @DevJuniorThe50421st

Comment: Sorry man! @mmm I said it sits all onto one line. When I copied and pasted I must of left the styles for the `li` tag out by mistake. My bad sorry!

Comment: @DevJuniorThe50421st -- No problem, didn't read that part... :-) Please see my edit..

Comment: @mmm thank you! I banged my head trying to get this to work for longer then I should of. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jquery, or don't want to use it, you could try to use .scrollIntoView()

MSDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

"The Element.scrollIntoView() method scrolls the current element into the visible area of the browser window."

though this is not implemented the same way in all the different browsers we got these days.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('item_1')[0].scrollIntoView();
```

Or you could assign an id to the first item, or pass this id: 'ul-main_wrapper'  and pass it to this example function

```
function scrollToAnchor(anchor) {
   var scrollLocation = document.location.toString().split('#')[0];
   document.location = scrollLocation + '#' + anchor;
}
```

which will do the scrolling for you.

If you do use jquery, use the solution by mmm